# How to execute Junit test and generate HTML result file just using one command line (use Maven surefire Plugin)

Tags: java, maven, junit

Now, to get HTML result file from Maven Surefire Report Plugin, I have to execute 2 command lines:

1. mvn test -Dtest=classname
2. mvn surefire-report:report

Is there any solution to combine these two command lines into one command line? I just need to make a shorter way instead of executing 2 commands as now.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[maven-surefire-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/) only supports 2 types of reports

```
Plain text files (*.txt)
XML files (*.xml)
```

You can use some plugins on your build system that can parse these reports and give you pretty HTML view

Comment: I added the below to POM file and execute "mvn test -Dtest=classname", but HTML file is not generated.

Comment: Could you please shed me a light?

Comment: <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
        <configuration>
          <showSuccess>false</showSuccess>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>

Comment: it does **not** generate HTML output, it generates XML output

Comment: Yes, Jigar Joshi. But when I execute "mvn surefire-report:report", It generates HTML output in "$(basedir)\target\site" folder.